# WPF C# .CS .Name is not being read on call

Tags: c#, wpf

My .Name is not being read on my border. How can I get it to read? Here is the code:

```
        Border Border1 = new Border();
        Border1.Name = "_webBrowserPlacementTarget";

        WebBrowserOverlayWF wbo = new WebBrowserOverlayWF(_webBrowserPlacementTarget);
```

I get a red line on the _webBrowserPlacementTarget. Also the code wont be executed and thus a program never forms. I tried using this code:

```
        public FrameworkElement _webBrowserPlacementTarget { get; set; }
```

But the window will not load. How can I have my .Name read?

Comment: explain more,, what are you doing and where is the problem exactly?

Comment: _webBrowserPlacementTarget

Comment: I get a red line under _webBrowserPlacementTarget and the code does not execute

Comment: I am trying to add a web browser on a border

Comment: Is it this:        `this.RegisterName(myRectangle.Name, myRectangle);`

Comment: You do understand that the `.Name` property and the name that the object is declared are two different things? So setting `Border1.Name = "_webBrowserPlacementTarget";` doesn't mean that you can now refer to `Border1` as `_webBrowserPlacementTarget` in code?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example here, maybe helps:

yourPanel is `StackPanel`.

```
        Border Border1 = new Border();
        Border1.Name = "_webBrowserPlacementTarget";

        yourPanel.Children.Add(Border1);

        var children = (yourPanel as Panel).Children;
        Border border = (from Border child in children
                         where child.Name == "_webBrowserPlacementTarget"
                         select child).First();
```

**EDIT:**

```
        Border Border1 = new Border();
        Border1.Name = "_webBrowserPlacementTarget";

        yourPanel.Children.Add(Border1);

        this.RegisterName(Border1.Name, Border1);
        var border = this.FindName("_webBrowserPlacementTarget");
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think that is SQL so that would not work. The code above is for a regular call.

Comment: Did you try this, it is not SQL, look likes SQL @user3034706

Comment: Is it this:  `this.RegisterName(myRectangle.Name, myRectangle);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use border element directly without registering a name

```
WebBrowserOverlayWF wbo = new WebBrowserOverlayWF(Border1);
```